# Change current csv data format in python (rows to column)

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a script where I fetch products from some website and save the data in csv format. Now the issue is some products have less specifications li's or td's and some has more where some products don't have it at all. I solved the problem of fetching specs but output data is stored in csv in A1, A2, A3 and so on format where i want it in A1, B1, C1 and so on.

This is an example csv data:

```
   A              B
1. ['Weight ']    ['0.3430']
2. ['Tag line']   ['Take Control']
3. ['Model']      ['Rhythm RX40']
4. ['Type']       ['Smart Phone']
5. ['Processor']  ['Dual Core']
```

Whereas what I need is:

```
   A            B                C               D               E
1. ['Weight ']  ['Tag line']     ['Model']       ['Type']        ['Processor']
2. ['0.3430']   ['Take Control'] ['Rhythm RX40'] ['Smart Phone'] ['Dual Core']
```

This is my python code:

```
with open('exampleCOM-'+ '(rivo)' +'-products.csv', 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for title in mainTree.xpath('(//*[@id="product_addtocart_form"]/div[@class="product-name"]/text())[2]'):
        title = title.strip()
        print (title)

    row_info = [title]

    csvwriter.writerow(row_info)

    while (mainTree.xpath("//tr[" + str(i) + "]")):
        specName = [specName for specName in mainTree.xpath("//tr[" + str(i) + "]/td[1]/text()")]

        spec = [spec for spec in mainTree.xpath("//tr[" + str(i) + "]/td[2]/text()")]

        row_info = [specName, spec]

        csvwriter.writerow(row_info)

        i += 1
```

What I tried:

```
row_info = [specName[1], specName[2], specName[3], specName[4], specName[5]]
row_info2 = [spec[1], spec[2], spec[3], spec[4], spec[5]]

csvwriter.writerow(row_info)
csvwriter.writerow(row_info2)
```

But I get `"IndexError: list index out of range"` error, where in my knowledge specName and spec lists should be of index size 5.

Comment: Python lists are 0-based.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Okay so How can i achieve my required format?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Would you please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on @DanielRoseman comment: The indexing of lists in python starts at zero. This means the following list

```
>>> l = [42, 23, 17]
```

contains three items

```
>>> len(l)
3
```

where the first item (at index 0) is 42 and the third item (at index 2) is 17:

```
>>> l[0]
42
>>> l[2]
17
```

There is not item at index 3 though, which would point to the fourth item in the list.

```
>>> l[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So your code would crash if you would use it with a list with five elements.

**Edit:**

In your case the error might originate from another point though. As far as I could understand the code (which means knowing nothing about the structure of the XML file you are working with) it seems as you would always get a list of length one for specName and spec. If you try to index this like shown in your code you would run into the index error there.

In your code you are fetching each specName / spec pair and directly write it to you output file. This also means, that you only have access to one specName / spec pair at a time, as you overwrite them with each iteration of your while loop.

To achieve your desired output format it might be easier to keep two lists (One for the spec names and one for the specs themselves) and bulk write the results after the loop.

```
# initilize empty lists to collect specNames and specs
specs = []
specNames = []

while (mainTree.xpath("//tr[" + str(i) + "]")):
    specNames.append([specName for specName in mainTree.xpath("//tr[" + str(i) + "]/td[1]/text()")])

    specs.append([spec for spec in mainTree.xpath("//tr[" + str(i) + "]/td[2]/text()")])

    i += 1

# write all specNames as first row
csvwriter.writerow(specNames)

# write all specs as second row
csvwriter.writerow(specs)
```

This saves you the trouble of converting and also works for an arbitrary number of specNames / specs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Than your lists most certainly do not have 5 items. You can check this by printing their length before executing the second code snippet (the one with row_info2 etc.) like `print(len(specName))`. My guess would be that you only get length one, if you execute the second snippet right after the first one.

Comment: Maybe I have found the problem. I am not 100% sure what you lxml(?) code does there (I have never worked with it and I do not know the structure of the file you are parsing.), so consider this an educated guess. I edited the answer.

Comment: Well this partially solves my problem, thanks. and yes it worked.